# Removing XML Node In Matching Context

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove element `bar` from

```
<data><foo>1</foo><bar><bla /></bar></data>
<data><foo>2</foo><bar><bla /></bar></data>
<data><foo>3</foo><bar><bla /></bar></data>
```

but only if `foo` matches `2`. So the result should looks like:

```
<data><foo>2</foo></data>
```

I use the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar[../foo = 2]" />
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You've used Identity transform template to recursively process the XML, and is the best suited way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way, but not sure if this will make any difference because the *matching* condition is quite simple in the first place :

```
<xsl:template match="data[foo = 2]/bar" />
```